# Will C++ with the Networking TR2 also have a standard thread pool implementation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, threadpool, c++-tr2

It seems the C++ Networking TR2 contains/is based on the ASIO library, which all-but-implements a thread pool - an extra [30 lines](https://gist.github.com/autosquid/c5e5b3964524130d1c4d) are sufficient for a rudimentary one - does that mean there will also be something like an `std::thread_pool` as part of it? Or beside it? If not - has that been proposed before and rejected?

<sub>Motivation: I'm probably going to need one soon, and I've noticed it's mostly "Oh, I've rolled my own, here's the GitHub link" situation - and thought I'd try to figure out what's likely to become standard, if anything.</sub>

Comment: Networking is in a *technical specification* (TS), not a TR. It hasn't been published yet; in fact, it only very recently started off with its initial [working draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/networking-ts).

Comment: @KerrekSB: I was actually thinking of [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2054.pdf) but I guess the R2 has evolved into an S (rather than a D2).

Comment: You mean that 10-year-old document? Yeah, we've moved on from that... :-)